# Adapting Armbian to use a tablet-style interface

Tags: android, asus, tablet, armbian

I'm building a home-brewed "tablet" using a 10" touchscreen hooked up to an Asus Tinkerboard. Ultimately I want it to function as much like an Android tablet as possible, but the Android distro supplied by Asus is exceedingly difficult to work with, so I'm looking to customize Armbian to have a more "tablet-like" interface. Unfortunately I don't see any obvious way to do that, as Armbian operates more like a standard desktop than a tablet.

Is there a package out there that can adapt Armbian for this purpose, or even an alternative to using Armbian that may be better-suited to my needs?

**Edit** for clarification: I want the device to recreate the experience of a consumer Android tablet, with an entirely touch-based interface, menus accessed by "pull-down", and a smooth touchscreen keyboard. Having access to the Google Play Store and Services would be excellent, but I can be flexible about that.

Currently the touchscreen works fine but it doesn't accept the same "gestures" (pulling menus, pinch zoom, etc.), touches are simply interpreted as mouse clicks on a desktop. There is also no context-sensitive keyboard (I've tried the matchbook keyboard but it's clunky to work with in this scenario).

Comment: As phrased now, this question is rather broad. Could you try and narrow down what exactly your expectations for a more "tablet-like" interface are, e.g. are you looking for applications with touch-friendly interfaces for particular tasks, or are you looking to make the desktop more compact to fit the smaller screen?

Comment: @ThomasNyman I've updated the question to be more explicit, let me know if that helps

Answer (score 1):

I don't have direct experience with these but I was able to find a couple of current things:

1. Canonical/Ubuntu just announced fairly recently (2018-02-04) a ["platform that runs both a mobile-based full touch interface and a true PC experience from a single smart device"](https://www.businesswire.com/news/home/20160204005033/en/Canonical-Reinvents-Personal-Mobile-Computing-Experience)
2. [postmarketOS](https://www.xda-developers.com/postmarketos-touch-optimized-linux-distro/) is a Touch-Optimized Linux Distro for Smartphones and Tablets

Comment: Thanks for the references, I'll have a look and see if they help

Comment: The announcement is from 201**6**, not 2018! Canonical dropped support of Ubuntu Touch in 2016 already.